# cant inflate fragment InflateException Error inflating class

Tags: android, android-layout, fatal-error, layout-inflater

I make the project that have simple drawer menu in left side, I make it with blanks whats gave me android studio, then I make fragments, and then click on drawer menu item the main content layout changes to that fragment I need, in my sony xperia all works fine no crashes but then I install it in tablet, then I click on drawer menu items it crashes, I don't know thats meter, can someone show me this onCreateView in fragment classes

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_kontakti).setChecked(true);
    if(rootView==null){
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_kontakti, container, false);
        findallcallbuttons();

    }

    return rootView;

}
```

and this is error

```
  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: *****************, PID: 31958
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at ******************.fragments.KontaktiFragment.onCreateView(KontaktiFragment.java:43)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
        at ******************.fragments.KontaktiFragment.onCreateView(KontaktiFragment.java:43) 
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595) 
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0200a4 a=-1 r=0x7f0200a4}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2124)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3579)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:494)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:188)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:183)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
        at ********.fragments.KontaktiFragment.onCreateView(KontaktiFragment.java:43) 
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595) 
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post the layout

Comment: There is a problem with the XML file you are trying to inflate. Can you post the code from that file (R.layout.fragment_kontakti)

Comment: @FlorentSpahiu i add

Comment: @Blackbelt i add below

Answer (score 0):

```
this is layout 

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context="*********.fragments.KontaktiFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="****"
        android:textColor="@color/bluedark"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="******"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_bluelight"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview_vidnoe1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                    android:paddingRight="3dp"
                    android:text="******"
                    android:textColor="@color/greenlight1"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_white_24dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textview_vidnoe2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="*****"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/kontacticall11"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_bluedark"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_call_white"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="******"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/kontacticall12"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_bluedark"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_call_white"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="*****"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/kontacticall13"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_bluedark"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_call_white"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="*******"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/kontacticall14"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_bluedark"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_call_white"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="*****"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="4">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/kontacticall15"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_bluedark"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_call_white"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="*****"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_bluelight"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview_kol1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                    android:paddingRight="3dp"
                    android:text="******"
                    android:textColor="@color/greenlight1"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_white_24dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textview_kol2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="******"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/kontacticall21"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_bluedark"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_call_white"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="******"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/kontacticall22"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_bluedark"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_call_white"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="*****"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="4">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/kontacticall23"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_bluedark"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_call_white"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="*****"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_bluelight"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview_yar1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                    android:paddingRight="3dp"
                    android:text="****"
                    android:textColor="@color/greenlight1"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview_yar2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_white_24dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="******"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/kontacticall31"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_bluedark"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_call_white"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="*****"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/kontacticall32"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_bluedark"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_call_white"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="******"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/kontacticall33"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_bluedark"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_call_white"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="*****"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/kontacticall34"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_bluedark"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_call_white"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="*****"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="4">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/kontacticall35"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_bluedark"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_call_white"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="*****"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="15dp"></LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Haven't you forgotten to add `</LinearLayout>` to the end of the XML? Is this layout shown correctly in a preview? Also, `tools:context="` should refer to an activity path, not a fragment.

Comment: @CoolMind the app works fine in my phone but when i test on tablet get crash

Comment: It doesn't matter. Have you tested on other devices or emulators? Do you have a fragment_kontakti layout in landscape mode?

Comment: @CoolMind yes i test im my phone all work fine but then i set it tu tablet it crashs, no landscape mode

Comment: Do you have at the end of file two `</LinearLayout>` or just one after `</ScrollView>`?

Comment: @CoolMind two </LinearLayout>

Comment: Then do so. 1) Comment most of the code in the fragment, so that it will simply show an XML. 2) In XML comment many blocks. Run the application in the tablet. If it's showing well, uncomment some blocks in XML, then run again. At least you will find a bug.

Comment: Also take a look at your `onCreateView` method. `inflater = ...` is redundant as it is already given in a method parameters. What is a `rootView`? Simply write: `View rootView = inflater.inflate(...);` without `if(rootView==null){`. Probably place `navigationView.getMenu()` below `rootView = inflater.inflate`. And rebuild your project, maybe. A problem may be even in a version of support-library.